# easeljs change origin 2d canvas translate

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

I need to change the origin of the canvas to the centre, in plain javascript I did this with:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 1024;
context.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);
```

Then if a shape is drawn with x, y of 0, 0 this will be draw in the centre of the canvas. How do define this in easlejs?

Answer (score 0):

To translate the origin of easeljs canvas, you will need to set the `x` and `y` property accordingly for the *stage*.

Here is an example, showing that in action ...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

// translate origin
stage.x = canvas.width / 2;
stage.y = canvas.height / 2;

// create shape
var circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill("#07C").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
stage.addChild(circle);
stage.update();
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #999}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EaselJS/0.8.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Works a treat

Comment: Note that scaling the stage should work, but it might be better it put your contents in a container, and scale that. Scaling the stage can have some odd consequences with mouse interaction, etc.